# Remove Object inside Array inside another Array Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
let bigArray = [
{
    Name: 'Alice',
    children: [
                 {Name: 'AliceChild1', Country: 'country1'}, 
                 {Name: 'AliceChild2', Country: 'country2'}
    ]
},
{
    Name: 'Bob',
    children: [
                 {Name: 'BobChild1', Country: 'country3'}, 
                 {Name: 'BobChild2', Country: 'country4'}
    ]
},
{
    Name: 'Sam',
    children: [
                 {Name: 'SamChild1', Country: 'country5'}, 
                 {Name: 'SamChild2', Country: 'country6'}
    ]
},
]
```

I want to remove an object from array inside another array. Property `Name` is unique. For an example if `BobChild2` is removed `bigArray` should return as

```
let bigArray = [
{
    Name: 'Alice',
    children: [
                 {Name: 'AliceChild1', Country: 'country1'}, 
                 {Name: 'AliceChild2', Country: 'country2'}
    ]
},
{
    Name: 'Bob',
    children: [
                 {Name: 'BobChild1', Country: 'country3'},
    ]
},
{
    Name: 'Sam',
    children: [
                 {Name: 'SamChild1', Country: 'country5'}, 
                 {Name: 'SamChild2', Country: 'country6'}
    ]
},
]
```

What is the best way to do this in JavaScript ?

Updated:
My answer

```
function removeChild(bigArray, childName) {
  let copyBigArray = []
  bigArray.forEach((item) => {
    let Obj = {
      Name: item.Name,
      children: item.children.filter(c => c.Name !== childName)
    }
    copyBigArray.push(Obj)
  })
  return copyBigArray
}
```

Comment: _"The best way"_ - why don't we start with the way you have tried, first?

Comment: `bigArray[1].children = bigArray[1].children.filter(child => child.Name === 'BobChild2')`?

Comment: @evolutionxbox  updated the question with my answer. :)

Comment: Why did you put an answer in the question? Why not just write an answer?

Comment: want to know is there a better and clean solution to this

Comment: Ah, that’s your attempt? Does it work? Or is it that you don’t like how it works?

Comment: this is working, yes i don't like, coz it has copy of bigArray and 9 lines.

Comment: `bigArray.forEach(function(o) {
  o.children = o.children.filter(s => s.Name != 'BobChild2');
});` this is better, answered by: @faramarz razmi

Answer (score 1):

Try this way:

```js
let bigArray = [{
    Name: 'Alice',
    children: [{
        Name: 'AliceChild1',
        Country: 'country1'
      },
      {
        Name: 'AliceChild2',
        Country: 'country2'
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    Name: 'Bob',
    children: [{
        Name: 'BobChild1',
        Country: 'country3'
      },
      {
        Name: 'BobChild2',
        Country: 'country4'
      }
    ]
  }
]


bigArray.forEach(function(o) {
  o.children = o.children.filter(s => s.Name != 'BobChild2');
});

console.log(bigArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

To support any nested depth you can do something like this:

```
function searchAndRemove(arr, query) {

    for (var i = arr.length; i > 0; i--) {

        if (query == arr[i].Name) {
            arr.splice(i, 1);
        }
    }
        
    if (arr.children) {
        searchAndRemove(arr.children, query);
    }
}

searchAndRemove(bigArray, 'BobChild2');
```

This will go through your array recursively until it finds all occurrences of `BobChild2` and removes them.

Comment: `arr: any[], query: string` what is this for?

Comment: @evolutionxbox I had missed the query argument for the inner function. Other than that I'm not sure what you mean?

Comment: It’s not standard JavaScript and I don’t see typescript in the tags nor being used in the examples?

Comment: @evolutionxbox Ah, old habit, lol. Updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example how you could achieve it:

```js
let bigArray = [
{
    Name: 'Alice',
    children: [
                 {Name: 'AliceChild1', Country: 'country1'}, 
                 {Name: 'AliceChild2', Country: 'country2'}
    ]
},
{
    Name: 'Bob',
    children: [
                 {Name: 'BobChild1', Country: 'country3'}, 
                 {Name: 'BobChild2', Country: 'country4'}
    ]
},
{
    Name: 'Sam',
    children: [
                 {Name: 'SamChild1', Country: 'country5'}, 
                 {Name: 'SamChild2', Country: 'country6'}
    ]
},
]


function filterName(name, data) {
  return data.reduce((arr, item) => {
    if (item.Name != name) {
      if (item.children) item.children = filterName(name, item.children)
      arr.push(item)
    }
    return arr  
  }, [])
}

console.log(filterName("BobChild2", bigArray));
```

Answer (score 0):

Well the structure isn't optimal because it'll require iterating over 2 arrays, but I'd use `filter()` *([documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter))* something like this:

```
function deepFilter(array, name) {
  return array.map(arr => {
     if (!arr || !arr.children) {
       return arr;
     }
     arr.children = arr.children.filter(c => c.Name !== name);
     return arr;
  })
}
```

Filter has to return a `Boolean` to know if the element should be returned or not.
Map has to return an element.

If you want to remove an element from the first Array once its children are empty, you could replace the `map` by a `filter`.

```
function deepFilter(array, name) {
  return array.filter(arr => {
     if (!arr || !arr.children || !arr.children.length) {
       return false;
     }
     arr.children = arr.children.filter(c => c.Name !== name);
     return arr && arr.children && arr.children.length;
  })
}
```

--

Use them by doing:

```
const new = deepFilter(bigArray, 'SamChild1')
```

Answer (score 0):

A main loop for the initial values of the array

Another loop for `children` values

The first parameter is the array itself that wants to be filtered, for example: `bigArray`

The second parameter is the value for the filter, for example: `BobChild2`

The third parameter is the key for the filter, for example: `Name`

```js
let bigArray = [{
        Name: 'Alice',
        children: [
            { Name: 'AliceChild1', Country: 'country1' },
            { Name: 'AliceChild2', Country: 'country2' }
        ]
    },
    {
        Name: 'Bob',
        children: [
            { Name: 'BobChild1', Country: 'country3' },
            { Name: 'BobChild2', Country: 'country4' }
        ]
    },
    {
        Name: 'Sam',
        children: [
            { Name: 'SamChild1', Country: 'country5' },
            { Name: 'SamChild2', Country: 'country6' }
        ]
    },
];

function filterBigArray(array, value, filter) {
    let result = [];
    bigArray.forEach(person => {
        let childs = [];
        person.children.forEach(children => {
            if (children[filter] !== value) {
                childs.push(children);
            }
        });
        result.push(childs);
    });
    return result;
}
let res = filterArray(bigArray, 'BobChild2', 'Name');
console.log(res);
```

You can also filter different keys, for example:

```
let res = filterBigArray(bigArray, 'country3', 'Country');
console.log(res);
```